# When defining a function, why do I need to return a function instead of returning the value I want straightaway?

Tags: javascript

I'm new to the concept of nesting a function within another function and I don't understand the need for returning a function instead of returning the value I want straightaway..

Appreciate any help in clearing my confusion!

1st method (What I would have instinctively written, but turned out to be wrong):

```
function wrapValue(n) {
  var localVariable = n;
  return localVariable;
}

var wrap1 = wrapValue(1);
var wrap2 = wrapValue(2);
console.log(wrap1());
console.log(wrap2());

// → Uncaught TypeError: number is not a function
```

I tried a simpler version of method 1 which works (method 1.1):

```
function wrapValue(n) {
  var localVariable = n;
  return localVariable;
}

console.log(wrapValue(6));
// → 6
```

2nd method (the correct method):

```
function wrapValue(n) {
  var localVariable = n;
  return function() { 
    return localVariable; 
  };
}

var wrap1 = wrapValue(1);
var wrap2 = wrapValue(2);
console.log(wrap1());
console.log(wrap2());

// → 1
// → 2
```

Why does method 1 not work when method 1.1 works? And why the need for method 2?

Thanks for the help!

Comment: In the first example you're trying to call `wrap1` as a function. Just use `console.log(wrap1)`.

Comment: Can't believe I missed that after staring at it for so long!! Thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Why does method 1 not work when method 1.1 works?

Because in method 1, you're trying to *call* the value you got back from `wrapValue` as though it were a function, but it isn't; it's a number (the number you passed in). In Method 1.1, you're using the return value directly, you're not trying to call it as though it were a function.

Let's break it down a bit:

```
var wrap1 = wrapValue(1);
```

Now, in `wrap1`, we have the number `1`. Not a *function*, just the number. So to use the number, we'd just use it directly:

```
console.log(wrap1); // 1
```

You can't *call* `wrap1` because the variable doesn't refer to a function, it contains a number.

> And why the need for method 2?

You only need method 2 if you have some reason that you need the access to `localVariable` to happen when you *call* the function `wrapValue` returns. Here's an example showing how that might change:

```
function doSomething(n) {
    var num = n;
    return function() {
        ++num;
        return num;
    };
}

var f = doSomething(0);
console.log(f()); // 1
console.log(f()); // 2
console.log(f()); // 3
```

Because calling the function `doSomething` returns *changes* the value of the `num` variable, we want to get the latest version each time we call it.

There I used a local variable to make it similar to your original example, but we could just use `n` directly:

```
function doSomething(n) {
    return function() {
        ++n;
        return n;
    };
}

var f = doSomething(0);
console.log(f()); // 1
console.log(f()); // 2
console.log(f()); // 3
```

Function arguments are effectively local variables in the function. (Effectively, not literally.)

Answer (score 0):

In your first exemple, you assign to wrap1 & 2 the return of the function which are numbers, and then you call the given numbers as functions.

```
var wrap1 = wrapValue(1); // wrap1 =  1;
var wrap2 = wrapValue(2); // wrap2 =  2;
```

Comment: JavaScript doesn't have ints, just numbers - this might add to confusion.

Answer (score 0):

You have an error in your first function, it should be:

```
function wrapValue(n) {
  var localVariable = n;
  return localVariable;
}

var wrap1 = wrapValue(1);
var wrap2 = wrapValue(2);
console.log(wrap1);
console.log(wrap2);
```

And that works as expected.

Answer (score 0):

Method 1 is simply just wrong.

When you call `wrapValue` you return `localVariable` which is set to `1` and `2`, those are numbers and cannot be called as functions.

This is also what you experience in method 1.1.

As for method 2, that could be a way to isolate variables that you do not want to flow into the parent scope. It is not useful in your example, but it is widely in cases where you immediately call the defined function, e.g.:

```
var myFn = function() {
    var hiddenVar = 1;

    return function() {
        return hiddenVar;
    };
}();
```

Answer (score 0):

I could answer your first question: Why does method 1 not work?

When you do `var localVariable = n;` you creates a new variable called `localVariable` and assigned it the **type** **number** and value n. And you return this **integer value n**.

Hence, `wrap1` and `wrap2` are numbers. They do not support `()` operation which only apply to functions. In method 1.1, you log `wrapValue(...)` directly which is the same as logging a number, which works.

Hope you could understand. :)